# stringr regex for first full *.zip filename

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following code:

```
test_zip_col          <- "daily_44201_2015.zip259,151 Rows2,958 KBAs of 2015-11-27"
test_zip_col2         <- str_extract(test_zip_col, '^*\\.zip$')
test_zip_col
test_zip_col2
```

I want to extract the first occurence of the `*.zip` filename. In this example, I wish to extract:

```
"daily_44201_2015.zip"
```

Could anyone please explain how to amend my `str_extract` code so that it does not produce an `NA` value?

Comment: With `stringi` it would be `stringi::stri_extract_first(test_zip_col, regex = ".*\\.zip")`

Comment: Hi - thanks. Per your suggestion I amended and used `stringr::str_extract(string = test_zip_col, pattern = ".*\\.zip")` and it worked. If you submit this as an answer I can accept as it is the most simple of the solutions offered

Comment: That wouldn't give you the first zip file in case of multiple zip files in one string. It works with stringi because there's a special function to extract the first match but not in stringr.

Comment: I could just subset the first one right?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
test_zip_col          <- "daily_44201_2015.zip259,151 Rows2,958 KBAs of 2015-11-27"
loc<-str_locate(test_zip_col,".zip") ## Locate the ".zip"
str_sub(test_zip_col,start=1, end=loc[,2]) # Substring 

[1] "daily_44201_2015.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `sub`

```
sub('(.*\\.zip).*', '\\1', test_zip_col)
#[1] "daily_44201_2015.zip"
```